# curl-free, conservative vector fields in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, analyticity

I just verified that for the *conjugate* of an analytic function $\bar{f}$=u-iv, this conjugate function is curl-free - the Cauchy-Riemann equations forces this to be the case.  Then we can consider f=u-iv as a conservative vector field, mapping $C-> C$.

But what can we say about f=u+iv?  Is it also conservative?

I can't verify that it is also curl-free, using the C-R equations.

Thanks,

Comment: What does it mean for a 2D vector valued function to be curl free? Curls exist in $\mathbb{R}^3$ only.

Comment: Hi @CameronWilliams, hmm..I know that the cross-product exists in $R^3$ only, and the computation of curl in 3D space uses the cross-product.  But, I think there is such a thing as curl in 2D?  Take f = <M,N>, then curl(f) = $N_x$ - $M_y$,  at least according to a set of notes from the MIT OCW page on YouTube :-)

Comment: @CameronWilliams One can define an operator sometimes called $\text{curl}_z$ that sends the $C^1$ vector field $P(x, y) \partial_x + Q(x, y) \partial_y$ defined on an open subset $U$ of $\Bbb R^2$ to $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$. Roughly speaking, this is the $z$-component of the curl of the given vector field (interpreted as a vector field on $U \times \Bbb R$).

Comment: I think, @CameronWilliams, that ultimately, my question and my wanting to make the connection between real and complex analysis is not so beneficial -- we get gradient (conservative) fields in real variables, but that is always assuming a simply connected domain.  In complex variables, the domain can be pretty bad ... and only in a simply connected domain, does the complex-analytic function have a chance to be conservative (connection with Cauchy-Goursat theorem).  But I want to believe it, since I have already verified it for the conjugate of f -- but not for f itself.

Comment: So, I want to say that "all holomorphic functions in a simply connected domain are curl-free and conservative, and integrate to zero on any closed contour that is contained in the domain -- which agrees with the Cauchy Goursat theorem." But I can't seem to say it for f(z), but only for its conjugate ...

Comment: Ahh I see now. I had a feeling this may have been what you meant but I wasn't totally sure. See this Wiki snippet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Harmonic_vector_field You are right that the curl-free and divergence-free properties are held by $\bar{f}$ **not** $f$.

Comment: While you may see that it is fruitless to try to relate fields on $\mathbb R^2$ to functions of $z$ (and not $\bar z$), the connection between complex analysis and vector calculus is still quite worthwhile to consider. For example, see that a divergence- and curl-free vector field can be described everywhere given its values on a closed surface, and compare this to the notion that a holomorphic function is determined by its values on a closed curve. This is not a mere coincidence; they are both consequences of generalized Stokes' theorem.